Fundamental Group of the Torus Using Covering Spaces
I am working on the fundamental group of the torus $ T = S^1 \times S^1 $ isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z})$ and used the covering space method for this. Here is my approach:

Representation: I represent the torus as $T = (\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}) \times (\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})= (\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}) / (\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z})$.

Covering Map: The universal cover of the torus is $\mathbb{R}^2$, and the covering map $ p: \mathbb{R}^2 \to T$ is given by
$
   p(x, y) = (x \mod 1, y \mod 1).
   $

Lifting a Loop: For a loop $\gamma: [0, 1] \to T$ with $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1)$, I consider a lift $\tilde{\gamma}: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $p \circ \tilde{\gamma} = \gamma$ and $\tilde{\gamma}(0) = (0,0)$. I concluded that the endpoint $\tilde{\gamma}(1)$ will be of the form $(m, n)$, where $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$. i.e. $(m,n )\in (\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z})$.


Is this method of using the covering map and the lifted endpoint to determine the fundamental group $\pi_1(T)$ correct?

This is the correct idea but you should mention hypotheses such as the most crucial one: $\Bbb R^2$ is simply connected.
For a full discussion of hypotheses for theorems of this ilk, see here: but we know from covering space theory (see Chapter $1$ of Hatcher’s “Algebraic Topology”) that if $G$ is a group with a covering space action on a path-connected space $Y$, then if $q:Y\to Y/G$ is the orbit-space quotient map we have $G\cong\pi_1(Y/G;q(y))/q_\ast(\pi_1(Y;y))$ for any choice of basepoint $y\in Y$. Thus, if $Y$ is also simply connected we fully compute $G\cong\pi_1(Y/G)$ at any basepoint. The isomorphism works by the method of loop-lifting that you mention, keeping track of endpoints.
In your case, $G=\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ acts suitably on the simply connected space $\Bbb R^2$, with orbit quotient the torus $T$, so $\pi_1(T)\cong\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$, where a loop’s class is determined by the pair $(m,n)$ of the endpoint of its lift - exactly as you say. But in your solution you didn’t seem to make use of the fact $\Bbb R^2$ is simply connected - that is very important, otherwise loops in the torus are not necessarily determined by that endpoint since there could be multiple, distinct homotopy classes of paths $(0,0)\to(m,n)$. Indeed the torus covers itself, but loops in the torus aren’t determined up to homotopy by their endpoints…

Hope now it make sense :
The torus $T = S^1 \times S^1$ as $T = (\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}) \times (\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{R}^2 / \mathbb{Z}^2$. The universal covering space of the torus is $ \mathbb{R}^2 $, and the covering map $p: \mathbb{R}^2 \to T$ is given by $p(x,y) = (x \mod 1, y \mod 1)$.
Using fact $\mathbb{R}^2$ is simply connected. i.e. $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ is trivial. Given a loop $\gamma: [0,1] \to T$ with $\gamma(0) = \gamma(1)$. Let $\tilde{\gamma}: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a lift such that $p \circ \tilde{\gamma} = \gamma$ and $\tilde{\gamma}(0) = (0,0)$.@FShrike

Since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is simply connected, the homotopy class of the loop $\gamma$ in $T$ is determined by the endpoint $\tilde{\gamma}(1) = (m,n)$, where $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$. This endpoint corresponds to an element of the group $\mathbb{Z}^2 = \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, the fundamental group $\pi_1(T)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, with the isomorphism given by the endpoint of the lift $\tilde{\gamma}(1)$.
Hence, $\pi_1(T) \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. @FShrike

@User1 Right. That argument is essentially complete. You say the usual things about uniqueness of lifts of paths and homotopies, and make the easy check that composition is preserved.

Uniqueness of lifts: a path $\gamma: [0,1] \to T$ and a starting point $(0, 0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, there is a unique lift $\tilde{\gamma}$ of $\gamma$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ up to adding an integer vector $(m,n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$.
Reasoning: If there are two lifts $\tilde{\gamma}_1$ and $\tilde{\gamma}_2$ starting from the same point $(0, 0)$, they must differ by a lattice vector in $\mathbb{Z}^2$. This follows from the fact that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is simply connected and the covering map $p: \mathbb{R}^2 \to T$ is a local homeomorphism. @FShrike

@User1 The reasoning is actually a technical basic lemma from covering theory, which Hatcher shows right at the start of chapter one. We need the full strength of a covering map, not just a local homeomorphism

uniqueness of homotopy: If two loops $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2 $ in $T$are homotopic, then their lifts in $\mathbb{R}^2$ starting from $(0,0)$ will have the same endpoint in $\mathbb{R}^2$. This is because homotopic loops lift to homotopic paths in the covering space, and thus their endpoints in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are the same. @FShrike

And composition :If $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are loops in $T$ based at a point, their lifts $\tilde{\gamma}_1$ and $\tilde{\gamma}_2$ start from the same point in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The composition $\gamma_1 \cdot \gamma_2$ corresponds to the sum of the integer vectors representing the endpoints of $\tilde{\gamma}_1$ and $\tilde{\gamma}_2$, preserving the group structure.
@FShrike

@User1 What you do for composition is, you take $\overline{\gamma_1}$ starting from $(0,0)$, it ends up at $(m,n)$, and then you decide to lift $\gamma_2$ starting from $(m,n)$ to get $\overline{\gamma_2}:(m,n)\to(a+m,b+n)$ and you realise that, just by applying the translation deck transformation that $(a,b)$ are the integers associated to $\gamma_2$, so $\gamma_1\cdot\gamma_2$ is lifted by $\overline{\gamma_1}\cdot\overline{\gamma_2}:(0,0)\to(a,b)+(m,n)$ and we have a group homomorphism!

is this i can use for uniqueness of lifts ? (ii) By the path-lifting theorem, there exists a unique path $\tilde{\gamma}: I \to X$ with $\tilde{\gamma}(0) = y_0$ and $p \circ \tilde{\gamma} = \gamma$. Since $(p(\tilde{\gamma}(0)) = p(\tilde{\gamma}(1))$, there is a unique element $g \in G$ such that $\tilde{\gamma}(1) = g \cdot y_0$ due to the unique lifting property. It is easy to check that such $g$ does not depend on the choice of $\gamma$ inside the homotopy class of $\gamma$ in $\pi_1(Y/G, b_0)$. Therefore, we get a well-defined map
$
\pi: \pi_1(Y/G, b_0) \to G.
$ @FShrike

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
